# Modal Views - internal page not loading

Tags: trigger.io

I have read through the [documentation](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/features/modal.html) and hopefully I am just missing the correct "file://" url syntax (or relative path) for forge (forge://).

My src directory contains a **local** file named noconnection.html.  My js directory contains a javascript file with the following code:

```
if (forge.is.connection.connected()) {
   // do cool stuff
} else {
   forge.tabs.open("noconnection.html");
}
```

Command line:

```
(forge-environment) forge run android
```

The modal "pops" up just fine (and has the little close button).  However, the page has a big "web page not available" error - the web page noconnection.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved.

I have tried these without success to correctly display my simple "no connection" modal:

```
forge.tabs.open("/noconnection.html");

forge.tabs.open("../noconnection.html");

forge.tabs.open("file:///noconnection.html");

forge.tabs.open("forge:///noconnection.html");
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?  Relative path?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the path to the local page, you need to use the forge.tools.getURL method like this:

```
if (forge.is.connection.connected()) {
   // do cool stuff
} else {
   forge.tools.getURL('noconnection.html', function(path) {
       forge.tabs.open(path);
   });
}
```